# Google Experiment Data Discrepancy

Tags: google-analytics, google-experiments

I am running a Google Experiment and I can't seem to find a reason for the transaction count discrepancy that I am seeing between the 'Conversions' tab and the 'Ecommerce' tab.  I am seeing identical numbers for the session count but a lower transaction count in the 'Conversions' tab than in the 'Ecommerce' tab.

Can anyone think of a reason for the discrepancy?  Both tabs claim to be based on 100% of sessions which should eliminate any sampling issues.

I've attached screenshots below of what I am seeing in Google Analytics.

**Conversion Tab**
[image]

**Ecommerce Tab**
[image]

Comment: One of them may be demonstrating a rounding error (I found, after much pain, that the Values returned on Google Tag Manager events have to be whole numbers if they are to be processed sensibly by GA).

Comment: @MandyShaw if that is the case, under Conversions > Ecommerce > Sales Performance, would you expect the revenue amounts to be round numbers?  I am able to see the decimal revenue amounts for each transaction.  Other than that, what numbers are you referring to that must be whole?  We send transactions one at a time so I'm not sure how the transaction count number could be anything other than whole.  Let me know if I'm missing something here.  Thanks for the input!

Comment: When I define an event in GTM I have found that the Value needs to be set to a whole number - when I used my transaction value with 2 decimal places, GA rounded it down. I fixed the problem by sending transaction value x 100 and tweaking the reporting accordingly. Sorry but I have not tried the ecommerce stuff.